# how do you declare a global variable using Angular Js?

Tags: angularjs

I want a variable that can be used in all the controllers but don't want to create a service for it .Is it possible in angular js?

Comment: It is possible - look at @Alan answer - but it is not recommended. What will the var contain ?

Comment: You should use Aseem's answer, leveraging the $rootScope for variables is considered a big design flaw in the angular world. Which is why services/factories exist.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can make use of [constants or values](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide).

**Constants**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.constant('appName', 'Application Name');

app.controller('TestCtrl', ['appName', function TestCtrl(appName) {
    console.log(appName);
}]);
```

**Values**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.value('usersOnline', 0);
app.controller('TestCtrl', ['usersOnline', function TestCtrl(usersOnline) {
    console.log(usersOnline);
    usersOnline = 15;
    console.log(usersOnline);
}]);
```

http://ilikekillnerds.com/2014/11/constants-values-global-variables-in-angularjs-the-right-way/

Answer (score 10):

Use `value()` to define an *object*, and store your 'global variables' as properties of that object. Then add the object as a dependency to any controller that needs to access its properties. This has a positive side-effect of encapsulating all your variables into a single object, which is tidy and less-likely to suffer namespace collision.

Here's the pattern:

```
app.value('myVars', {
    usersOnline:0
});
app.controller('TestCtrl', ['myVars', function TestCtrl(myVars) {
    console.log(myVars.usersOnline);
    myVars.usersOnline = 15;
    console.log(myVars.usersOnline);
}]);
```

FYI Aseem's answer won't work, because his example uses `value()` with a primitive type. To be clear about what doesn't work:

```
app.value('usersOnline', 0);
app.controller('TestCtrl', ['usersOnline', function TestCtrl(usersOnline) {
    console.log(usersOnline);
    usersOnline = 15; // <-- THIS WILL NOT PERSIST outside the controller.
    console.log(usersOnline);
}]);
```

Comment: Matthew is exactly right. If failed to define value as an Object, the changing value inside a particular controller doesn't get prolonged outside.

Answer (score 3):

You could set that variable on $rootScope. and inject $rootScope into the controllers which will use the global.