# How to declare global variable in angularjs app.js?

Tags: angularjs, global-variables

How to declare global variable in angularjs **app.js** ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do you declare a global variable using Angular Js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31723546/how-do-you-declare-a-global-variable-using-angular-js)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [contants](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant) which can be injected anywhere in the app.

```
app.constant('MOVIE_TITLE', 'The Matrix');
```

Or if it's a value that is likely to change, use [values](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#value)

```
app.value('movieTitle', 'The Matrix');
```

values can't be injected in `config` though.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that would come to your mind would be declaring variables in $rootScope. But's that's a very bad idea and should be avoided. You can use factories or services, but that's a little bit complex. The easiest way would be using **Constants and Values**. Refer the below article:

https://ilikekillnerds.com/2014/11/constants-values-global-variables-in-angularjs-the-right-way/